# Find unknown angles of a triangle!!!

Tags: triangles, angle

I am unable to find out the unknown angles for the following triangle which I attached with this post.

[image]

**Angle BAD** and **angle BCD** are the unknown angles need to be calculated. Given that lines **AB=BC=CD** and **angle CDE** = **108 degrees**

From my calculations: **angle ADC** = 180 - 108 = **72 degrees** (angles on a straight line)

**angle BAD** + **angle BCD** = **108 degrees** (exterior angle of a triangle = sum of interior opposite angles)

I could not proceed any further beyond this. I thought **line DB** (median) is bisecting **angle ADC** since **line DB** is bisecting **line AC** (AB=BC) but this only happens in case of isosceles and equilateral triangles.

I am very much stuck here and seek your kind suggestions here. I am also suspecting something could be wrong in the diagram of the triangle or may be the unknown angles. Let me know where I am wrong. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can use latex. It will be better.

Comment: Angle CDE cannot be 108 degrees as angle CAD is 26.6 degrees and angle CDE must be 90 + angle CAD. Unless of course A, D and E are not on a line.

Comment: @Jens How did you find $\angle CAD=26.6°$

Comment: @tatan The triangle is a 1, 2, $\sqrt 5$ triangle.

Comment: @Jens it will be better if you elaborate.

Comment: @tatan Perhaps I'm mistaken. I assumed the angle ACD was a right angle.

Comment: @Jens Yeah...diagram is a bit misleading...

Answer (score 1):

Hint- 
Using [Law of Sines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_sines)-

$$\frac{CD}{\sin\angle A}=\frac{AC (=2CD)}{\sin\angle ADC(=72^{\circ})} \implies \sin\angle A=\frac{\sin72^{\circ}}{2}$$

Hope this helps!!

Comment: Thanks, but is it possible to solve this question without using trigonometry concepts? I tried using geometry principles but in vain.

Comment: @tantrik As you can see, the angles are irrational. Hence, I don't think you  can do it without trigonometry.

Answer (score 0):

Can you use trigonometry?

By the law of sines, and letting $\angle CAD = \theta$,

$\frac{\sin \theta}{1} = \frac {\sin 72^{\circ}}{2}$

$\sin \theta = \frac 12\sin 72^{\circ}$

I'm pretty sure trigonometry is needed here because the answer is not "nice" (in degrees at least).

Comment: I don't see a need of having two exactly similar answers.

Comment: @tatan Hadn't you deleted yours?

Comment: No...its there till now....

Comment: @tatan I am pretty sure I saw it was deleted a while back.

Comment: You can see the time it was answered...

Comment: @tatan Yup, it's right there in your log. Deleted, then undeleted. I was ready to post mine, saw yours was up, then suddenly saw it deleted and decided to go ahead.

Comment: A technical error, I suppose. But I almost instantly undid it

Comment: Ok...no problem....you can keep yours and I can keep mine...;-)

Comment: Nevertheless, I don't think either of us needs to actually debate on that.

Comment: @tatan Why are you still posting comments then? I am prepared to drop it.

Comment: For this question concepts in geometry need to be used not trigonometry. I tried using trigonometry concepts, got the same answer like yours. Thanks

Comment: @tantrik I doubt very much there's a geometric solution. At least an elementary one.